# Best API for reading a huge .pdf file from java

Tags: java, sql, api, pdf

I have a huge pdf file (20 mb/800 pages) which contains some information.

It has got index with hyperlinks. Also most of the remaining information is in Tabular format (in pdf). I need to retrieve this information using Java and store it in SQL Server.

Which is the best API available to read this kind of file from Java?

Comment: Are you trying to read the text from the PDF file and store it in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely to be in tabular format inside the PDF as PDF does not contain structure information unless explicitly added at creation time. I wrote an article explaining some of the issues with text extraction from at PDF at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/04/pdf-text/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php):

- [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)
- [Download iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/)
- [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/)
- [List of the Examples](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php)